# Using tabbed pane for multiple form data insertion from php into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, tabs

I am creating an application in Html, php with Mysql. On one of my webform I am using Tabs created with Radio buttons as tab heads to select the tab perticular tab. I am facing the issue to insert tab1 values into the database while other 4 tabs fire same query and their data is easily inserted. Its the problem with the 1st Tab only and I realized it when I changed the tabs order. Please help me I want to work with Tabbed pane to provide multiple input forms to the user. Thanks in advance.

Here here is my web form Tab1.php

```
<form action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td> Date </td>
      <td><input type="DATE" required name="ClaimDate"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>From</td>
      <td><input type="text" maxlength="" required size="20" Placeholder="Source" name="ClaimFrom"></td>
      <td align="center">To</td>
      <td><input type="text" size="20" maxlength="" required Placeholder="Destination" name="ClaimTo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount</td>
      <td><input type="number" size="5" name="ClaimAmt" required Placeholder="In Rupees" ></td>
      <td colspan = 3><input type="file" name="ClaimReceipt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6"  ><table border="0" Width="30%" height=40px >
          <tr>
            <td width="20%" ><input type="submit" name="Add"  value="Add"></td>
            <td width="20%" ><input name="AdBtn3" type="reset" value="clear" width="48" height="40" ></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

InsertData.php

```
include('dbcon.php');
               $User = 'abc';
              $ExCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ExCategory']);
              $ClaimDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ClaimDate']);
                if(isset($_REQUEST['ClaimFrom']) && isset($_REQUEST['ClaimTo']))
                {
                    $ClaimFrom = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ClaimFrom']);
                    $ClaimTo = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ClaimTo']);
                }
              $ClaimAmt = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ClaimAmt']);
              $ClaimClass = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ClaimClass']);
              $ClaimReceipt = $_FILES['ClaimReceipt']['size'];
              $ClaimRowid = "";

    if (isset($_POST['Add']))
    {
                  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test`.`tbluserexpenses` VALUES('$User','$ExCategory','$ClaimDate','$ClaimFrom','$ClaimTo','$ClaimAmt','$ClaimClass','$ClaimReceipt','$ClaimRowid');");
    }
```

Comment: you need to provide your back end code that's processing the form

Comment: cmorrissey I have added it. please check it. i am using <?php include('Tab1.php'); ?> in the upper section of InsertData.php form so I haven't given action="" value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index:1; top:85px; left:390px;"><ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Local</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
    <?php include 'Tab1.php';?>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Express</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
    <?php include 'Tab2.php';?>
    </div>
</li>
```

This way Tab1.php is attached to my mainform as a tabbed pane.